# Toast created in an IntentService never goes away

Tags: android

I have an IntentService that downloads some files.  The problem is that I create a Toast inside the IntentService like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The Toast will never disappear event if I exit the app.  The only way to destroy it is to kill the process.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no reason not to create a Toast from a service. From [the notification dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html):
>If you create a toast notification from a Service, it appears in front of the Activity currently in focus.

Comment: That must be wrong, because it doesn't work when you test it with IntentService.  @rony's solution works best.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You shouldn't create `Toast`s from a `Service`. You should use a [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) instead.

Comment: Wrong. from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html  "A toast can be created and displayed from an Activity or Service". Its not working because "Service" runs on Main thread, whereas "Intent service" run on another thread.

Comment: Just because you can do a thing doesn't mean you should do a thing. You shouldn't create toasts from a service.

Comment: @Qberticus, can you update your answer with a code example of how Notification would be used in this case?

Comment: Why should we use `Notification`s instead of `Toast`s from services? Is it because of a technical limitation? Is it because the user mightn't be looking at the screen?

Answer (score 75):

The problem is that `IntentService` is not running on the main application thread. you need to obtain  a `Handler` for the main thread (in `onCreate()`) and post the `Toast` to it as a `Runnable`.

the following code should do the trick:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MyIntentService.this, "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @rkmax android studio for some reason defaults to `import java.util.logging.Handler;` (which is abstract) change it to `import android.os.Handler;`

Comment: @rony If I call this from JNI I get a null pointer exception, any idea why that is? Do I need a new thread in JNI?

Comment: Is new Handler() call expensive?

Answer (score 24):

This works for me:

```
public void ShowToastInIntentService(final String sText) {
    final Context MyContext = this;

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MyContext, sText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 8):

IntentService will create a thread to handle the new intent, and terminated it immediately once the task has done. So, the Toast will be out of controlled by a dead thread.

You should see some exceptions in the console when the toast showing on the screen.

Comment: +1 for pointing out worker thread mechanism in IntentService.

Answer (score 1):

For people developing in Xamarin studio, this is how its done there:

```
Handler handler = new Handler ();
handler.Post (() => {
    Toast.MakeText (_Context, "Your text here.", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a toast when the user is in one of the application activity.

Just need a reference of the current activity, and call it with this sample code:

```
public void showToast(final String msg) {
    final Activity a = currentActivity;
    if (a != null ) {
        a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(a, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is a lot of options to get the current activity, check this question:
[How to get current foreground activity context in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android)

But I use this approach:

The application must have:

```
private Activity currentActivity = null;

public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    return currentActivity;
}

public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity) {
    this.currentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
}
```

Each activity must have:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setCurrentActivity(this);

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setCurrentActivity(null);
}
```

Comment: Call `super.onPause()` from `onPause`

Comment: Oh my god a bug!... But it's gone now.