# java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: android, android-intent, service, handler, runtimeexception

in my app I'm using IntentService for sending SMS.

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    String[] recipients = null;
    String message = getString(R.string.unknown_event);
    String name = getString(R.string.app_name);
    if (data != null && data.containsKey(Constants.Services.RECIPIENTS)) {
        recipients = data.getStringArray(Constants.Services.RECIPIENTS);
        name = data.getString(Constants.Services.NAME);
        message = data.getString(Constants.Services.MESSAGE);
        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            if(!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(recipients[i])) {
                try {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, SMSReceiver.class);
                    sendIntent.setAction(Constants.SMS.SEND_ACTION);
                    PendingIntent sendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(this, SMSReceiver.class);
                    deliveryIntent.setAction(Constants.SMS.DELIVERED_ACTION);
                    PendingIntent deliveryPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, deliveryIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(recipients[i].trim(), null, "[" + name + "] " + message, sendPendingIntent, deliveryPendingIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "sendTextMessage", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MainActivity.instance.writeToLogFile(e.getMessage(), System.currentTimeMillis());                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when running the app, I get the following error:

```
W/MessageQueue(7180): Handler (android.os.Handler) {42586468} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(7180): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {42586468} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:618)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:587)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:558)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:323)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:367)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:55)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
W/MessageQueue(7180):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

My SMSReceiver is located in another class.
How can i solve this problems?
Thanks;
Eyal.

Comment: did you add this service to the manifest ?

Comment: Yes. IntentService is a real service after all...

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating a `Toast` inside a thread that is managed by the `IntentService`. The system will use the `Handler` associated with this thread to show and hide the `Toast`.

First the `Toast` will be shown correctly, but when the system tries to hide it, after the `onHandleIntent` method has finished, the error "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" will be  thrown because the thread on which the `Toast` was created is no longer valid, and the `Toast` will not disappear.

To avoid this you should show the `Toast` posting a message to the Main Thread. Here's an example:

```
    // create a handler to post messages to the main thread
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @rubenlop88 I still don't get how the problem is solved when I use a runnable. What I understand is that the problem is, when onHandle is called, it will call the Toast, and then it will exit, and after that Toast will be hidden? Is that the sequence, but then if that is the case, then when I use runnable, then also, the runnable thread should kill itself before it hides the Toast. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: @Kraken The `Runnable` is used to create the `Toast` on the main thread of the application. If you don't use a `Runnable` the `Toast` will be created in a thread managed by the `IntentService`. If the thread of the `IntentService` finishes too quickly then the `Toast` wont be dismissed.

Comment: Great. work properly, but for my case the problem was that Toast is not shown at all.

Answer (score 5):

Display **Toast** on *IntentService*.
try this code..

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MyIntentService.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }
    });
}
```

source :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420929/4565853

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check a condition:

```
mHandler.getLooper().getThread().isAlive()
```

The application will just warn you about this error. Of course it s mostly not fatal one.
But if there are many spawned usages of this handler these warnings will slow down the application.