# How to display Toast from a Service after main Activity finishes?

Tags: android, service, android-service, toast, android-toast

**UPDATE:**  I don't agree that this is a duplicate - because I am seeking for a way to exit the main app and still show a Toast from the service.

In [a very simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q12/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification) I have 2 buttons:

[image: screenshot]

Clicking any of the buttons will run a service with a corresponding action string ("open" or "flash") -

[OpenActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q12/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/OpenActivity.java):

```
public class OpenActivity extends Activity {
    private Intent mServiceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open);
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, RegionService.class);
   }

    public void openCar(View v) {
        mServiceIntent.setAction("open");
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
```

[RegionService.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q12/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/RegionService.java):

```
public class RegionService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "RegionService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received an intent: " + intent);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "Received an action: " + action);

        if(action.equals("open")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
                    getString(R.string.car_opened), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Unfortunately my app crashes with:

```
D/RegionService(24506): Received an intent: Intent { act=open cmp=de.afarber.mynotification/.RegionService }

D/RegionService(24506): Received an action: open

W/MessageQueue(24506): Handler (android.os.Handler) {422768a8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(24506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {422768a8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:370)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:54)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:412)
W/MessageQueue(24506):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Being an Android programming newbie I wonder **How to display a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) from Service in a correct way?**

I think I've already seen Toasts at Android Home (i.e. there was no Activity on the device screen and still there were Toasts).

**My background:** I would like to monitor a beacon device from my service and show some text Toasts - even when my app has been closed.

Comment: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/09/show-toast-notification-from-service.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toast created in an IntentService never goes away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296639/toast-created-in-an-intentservice-never-goes-away)

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate - because in my case I'd like to exit the main app and still show a Toast from the service.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`OnHandleIntent` will run in a differant `Thread` 
so you are showing `Toast` in a thread which is not allowed in android

so change your code like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       getString(R.string.car_opened), 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
    }
});
```

From this [dead thread in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296639/toast-created-in-an-intentservice-never-goes-away/16766109#16766109)

IntentService will create a thread to handle the new intent, and terminated it immediately once the task has done. So, the Toast will be out of controlled by a dead thread.

You should see some exceptions in the console when the toast showing on the screen.

Comment: I've tried putting your code excerpt into [onHandleIntent](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q12/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/RegionService.java) - but it does not compile because of **this** being a `Runnable`.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber place YourService.this instead of this or chaneg to getApplicationContext()

Comment: If anyone still have trouble getting the Toast displayed, just override onCreate and initialize the Handler here instead of initializing in onHandleIntent(). Only call the post method in onHandleIntent().

Comment: This is not working on android 13

Answer (score 5):

> An IntentService has a few limitations:
>
> It can't interact directly with your user interface. To put its
>   results in the UI, you have to send them to an Activity.

Everything is happening in the background thread and not on the UI thread, so you need a different way as shown below:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate(); 
    mHandler = new Handler(); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            Toast.makeText(MyIntentService.this, "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Source: [Toast created in an IntentService never goes away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296639/toast-created-in-an-intentservice-never-goes-away)

Answer (score 2):

`OnHandleIntent` is called on a background thread, and any attempt to touch the UI will result in a crash. Use an Handler to post a Runnable on the UI Thread to show your toast.

```
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

   final int mTextId = -1; 
   final Context mContext;
   public MyRunnable(Context c, int textId) {
       mTextId = textId;
       mContext = c;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(mContext, 
           getString(mTextId), 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
    }
}

   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.post(new MyRunnable(this, R.string.car_opened));
```

Comment: Why dont you give all these code snippets a try? :)

Comment: Of course I try the snippets, but sometimes bugs/crashes are not immediately visible (especially when something runs in background) - that is why it is good to ask.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
    });
```

Comment: yes it shows even when service is running in background

Comment: Activity instance can be passed to a service

Comment: That is true, you will also leak the instance once you rotate the screen. You don't need the activity to access the main thread.

Comment: It works but toast can also be shown using service context directly.

Comment: You can use any context to create the toast **BUT** the point is you have to call `Toast.show()` on UI thread for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem because of not running the Toast from the main_thread, and to overcome that,
when creating the Activity save it's context from `onCreate()` method:

```
public static Context ctx;

// the method responsible for running the MainActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ctx = this;
}
```

then, in the service add a handler and run a thread from it(as the Handler is executed through the main Thread):

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(OpenActivity.ctx, getString(R.string.car_opened),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: why is there a need to store `this`?

Comment: @LittleChild as I don't know the Thread state of his service and don't have an overview of the app structure and threads, unsaving it will mostly work but in some cases won't, So I saved it to make sure that it will certainly run.

Comment: You can take a look at my complete app at https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q12/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification

Comment: @AlexanderFarber there isn't a problem in that, not good or bad, but it makes you make sure that you won't go into trouble with serviceintent context.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat You mean just in case the service gets destroyed unexpectedly??

Comment: @LittleChild yes, gets destroyed or anything else happened that can make it stop.